# Find the port number of a specific process by using the PID

Tags: linux, unix, netstat

I am a newbee in this. I am using Netstat to find the port number of a specific PID. I have used the following comman to find the PIDs of all the process. My goal is to search for the port number only by using the PID of a process.I am using Linux, certain options like **find**,**findstr** is not working, so I tried the Following commands. Kindly give some suggestion. Thanks in advance

```
netstat -anop
```

[image]

To show the port number I have used the following code by PID

```
sudo netstat -anpe | grep ${#PID}
```

Comment: Do `grep ${PID}`  not `grep ${#PID}`.

Comment: I have tried sudo netstat -anpe | grep ${7801} #7801 is the PID. But not working.

Comment: It's `| grep 7801` not `| grep ${7801}`. `But not working` is very vague - please be specific. Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Sorry for that. Previuosly it showed 'grep --help' After following your advice now it shows the state, along with I-node. How can I view the port number?

Comment: Ports numbers are in 3rd and 4th column, separated by `:`.

Comment: Thanks but Is it possible to only view the port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port number is shown after the local or foreign address, is the number followed by the semicolumn, i.e. :

```
192.168.43.6:42010   198.252.206.25:443
```

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to only view the port address? from your example 42010 for the first one and 443 for the last one

Comment: To view only the port number you can filter it out with awk, something like `netstat -anop | grep 123 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d ":" -f2`

The `$5` (that you'll need to adapt anyway) from awk tells to print only the n-th column from the left of the ouput, i.e. `192.168.43.6:42010`; the `cut` option -d allows to specify a separator, while the -f number tells cut to print only the n-th field of the "cutted" string.

Comment: Another thing I have showed both the coulmn  `netstat -antup | grep 3833 | awk '{print $4 "\t"  $5 }' | cut -d ":" -f2` but the second column is showing the ip address, not the port number. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you try to print both on the same line, `cut` will process the first delimiter it matches and return the output until the next delimiter. This means that you are printing only what is between the two semicolumns of `192.168.43.6:42010   198.252.206.25:443`.